# Test if duplicate + retrieve data of duplicate row in SQL Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Sorry if the title isn't all that clear, I'll try to clarify here. So I have a table called `Companies`, with columns `CompanyName`, and `ID` (and others that are irrelevant to this question).

I have some other code in Visual Studio that will retrieve company names, and I want to make it so that if there's already a row that exists with that company name, I can retrieve its ID, and if it doesn't exist, it creates a new row, and returns the ID back to Visual Studio.

[image]

So in that screenshot (sorry that it's small but I want to be cautious about screenshoting other rows), if I get "XYZTestCompany" as a result, I want to only retrieve 3, but if I got a new company, it would create a new row, with say ID #25, and retrieve 25.

I've looked at related questions, but I can't tell if they would solve this problem. Help would be appreciated while I look for a possible solution.

Comment: Make sure there's a unique index, then I'd either use raw sql or a procedure to ensure the result is atomic (as much as possible anyway). I don't think EF has an insert-or-update primitive at all. Maybe when EF Core implements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#map-cud-operations-to-stored-procedures you could treat all companies as new, merging them during `.SaveChanges`

Answer (score 1):

To be efficient you would want to have an index on the company name /w a unique constraint. Domain logic like this is a good reason to consider a domain wrapper pattern like Decorator, though I generally simplify this to be a feature of a Repository pattern to isolate and standardize data access. For example:

```
public Company GetCompanyByName(string companyName)
{
    var company = _context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == companyName);
    if (company == null)
        company = CreateCompany(companyName);
    
    return company;
}

public Company CreateCompany(string companyName)
{
    var company = new Company { CompanyName = companyName };
    _context.Companies.Add(company);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return company;
}
```

This example does not use a Unit of Work, but rather an injected DbContext which would likely be scoped to the request. There are limitations with this where you typically want to avoid situations where DbContext `SaveChanges` shouldn't be called more than once as you can end up with poisoned state if something fails, blocking further save operations. With a Unit of Work pattern you would want to ensure the UoW is scoped so that the DbContext SaveChanges occurs before you attempt to get the Id from a potentially new Company.

For instance, if I am using the DbContextScope UoW:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string companyName)
{
    using (var contextScope = _contextScopeFactory.Create())
    {
        var company = _repository.GetCompanyByName(companyName);
        contextScope.SaveChanges(); 
        return Content(company.CompanyId); <-- The ID cannot be relied upon until after SaveChanges.
    }
}
```

Comment: So far I've been using DBContext to retrieve data from a different table, and I only plan on creating these new rows when a button is clicked, so it's not in a loop or anything. Is that still a problem? Also Visual Studio automatically generates DbContext files so it's kinda convenient.

Comment: Also, for the SingleOrDefault line, how do I check 2 columns? There's a CompanyName column as well as a CompanyName_Formal column, and I want to make sure that it's not in either one. Thanks.

Comment: You can use logical ands and ors in your query. For instance to ensure that the name is unique across both the CompanyName and CompanyName_Formal: `_context.Companies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == companyName || c.CompanyName_Formal == companyName);`

Note that in this case the database will not be able to assist guarding that a name is unique across both fields, so you have to be careful with any cases where data could be inserted/modified whether in an app or externally because SingleOrDefault will (and should) throw if two records happen to have that name.

Comment: I.e. one company has a CompanyName of "Joe's Boots" while a different company has a CompanyName_Formal of "Joe's Boots". The DB unique constraints won't enforce that value being unique across those two fields.

Comment: So I found one where the CompanyName and CompanyName_Formal are both "WEB". Will that affect anything?

Comment: Yep, that would break the `Single`.  You should raise that with the client/business to determine if that unique rule is needed whether that "Web" can/should be altered to conform to the rule. Worst case you have to add an explicit case to handle "Web".

Comment: Would it make a difference if I used FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Actually, re-reading, if it is the same record that has the Name and Formal Name of "Web" then `Single` is fine. It would only be an issue if one record had the Name set to "Web" and a different record had a Name_Formal set to "Web".